# SpringBoot configuring BeanNameGenerator to use Qualifier names

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, proguard

I am using proguard to obfuscate my code and to tackle duplicate bean definition names, I am using custom bean name generator to register beans with fully qualified names.

```
public static class CustomGenerator implements BeanNameGenerator {

    @Override
    public String generateBeanName(BeanDefinition definition, BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
        return definition.getBeanClassName();

    }
}
```

Then I am creating application context using the custom name generator

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new SpringApplicationBuilder(DataQualityApplication.class)
            .beanNameGenerator(new CustomGenerator())
            .run(args);
```

The issue however is that the beans are now being registered using their corresponding class types and not by the qualifier names provided in the `@Qualifier` or `@Component`.
How can I achieve this in my project?

Comment: Just extend the default one (`AnnotationBeanNameGenerator`) and override the `buildDefaultBeanName` method to use the logic you have. That will keep the original behavior and when no explicit name uses the full classname.

Comment: Yes, solved the problem using the exact approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve it by extending AnnotationBeanNameGenerator rather than implementing the BeanNameGenerator interface

```
public static class CustomGenerator extends AnnotationBeanNameGenerator {

    @Override
    public String generateBeanName(BeanDefinition definition, BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {

        UnaryOperator<String> fun=pkgName->{
             int lastIndex = pkgName.lastIndexOf ('.');
            if (lastIndex!=-1){  
                pkgName=pkgName.substring (0, lastIndex);
            }
            return pkgName;
        };
        String className = super.generateBeanName(definition, registry);
        String packagename = definition.getBeanClassName();
        return (fun.apply(packagename) + "." + className);
    }
}
```

This returns fully qualified names with qualifier/component name if annotated otherwise class name.
Solves the duplicate bean definition error in Proguard jar.

Comment: Why the complexity, you should be overriding the `buildDefaultBeanName` method and return the name. You are currently processing everything, which isn't necessary. It now also modifies the name if an explicit name is given through `@Component(name="foo")`. The name will now change to `your.package.foo` instead of only `foo` if you are using qualifiers or name based injection that will start to fail.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, added the changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the class name as bean name, that means you can have only one bean per type. In this situation, the injection can be done by type only, just remove the @Qualifer and don't name your beans, this should work fine. If you have several beans for the same class, you can't use your generator.

Comment: Is there a way I can use qualifier name instead of `return definition.getBeanClassName();` in my name generator so that it registers beans having qualifier with the qualifier names and for all others uses classnames